# VB6 Timestamp / datediff()?

Tags: vb6

I have a series of steps say 1-10 and some of the steps repeat multiple times. I am able to record the time stamp do some simple calculation and write it into a text file at the steps where I want but the problem is when the same step repeats again it is recording it again. How can I record this timestamp only once at the start of the step and not record again when the step repeats?

Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to say, but assuming these 'steps' are separate subroutines or functions you could just use a static boolean variable in each function which is set to True the first time you record your timestamp. Then check it on subsequent passes and don't record the timestamp if it **is** set. Incidentally the title your question could have been better worded.  It has nothing to do with DateDiff()!

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read up on [ask]. Then post a [mre] so we can actually see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided many details so the answer might be not relevant. As an option, you can use a flag variables declared somewhere outside of your steps. For example for step one:

```
Private Step1Called As Boolean
```

Later, when you enter your step number 1 you can add something like this, where RecordTimeStamp is a function creating and manipulating your timestamp:

```
If Not Step1Called Then
    RecordTimeStamp
    Step1Called = True
End If
```